# Datestyle issue in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Using: **postgresql**
Table name: **my_data**

I have the following column **current_time** of type `timestamp` in my table. The inputs to this field looks like this:

"4/26/2014 5:27:48 PM"

I'm reading this table from a csv file and I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "4/25/2014 5:29:37 PM"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY my_data, line 2, column current_time: "4/25/2014 5:29:37 PM"
```

I looked for solution and tried this, but it couldn't help me:

```
set datestyle = "ISO, DMY";
```

Please help me on how to read this file in a proper `timestamp` format.

Comment: Well `"4/25/2014 5:29:37 PM` isn't an ISO timestamp format. The ISO format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`

Comment: is there a way to read this format in postgresql? or at least read this and convert to proper format later?

Comment: Looks like the dreaded MDY (+time) format to me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example uses the `MDY` (**M**onth before **D**ay) styled date. So you would need something like

```
SET DateStyle TO MDY;
```

But generally, it's more safe to use the [`ISO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) format. Try to pass that format first, and if you can't you could use the [`to_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html) function for converting between formats.

```
SELECT to_timestamp('4/25/2014 5:29:37 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM');
```

Comment: I'm new to `SQL` so can you please eloborate if I have to read this column as `varchar` first and then convert it using `to_timestamp()` or directly read it as `timestamp`.

Comment: Where does this data comes from? The first approach should be giving postgres the preferred format (ISO), and if that's not possible, supply that expression (the to_timestamp call) to your insert / update statements.

Comment: The data is being read from a `CSV` file into the table. So, what could be the approach given that postgres is not able to detect the preferred format?

Comment: If you working with some scripting (which parses the csv) i would look for a way to transform dates to the preferred format in that scripting language, or use the to_timestamp function upon inserting a row from the csv. If you are using the `COPY` command in postgres, probably that best approach is to temporary set the datestyle configuration to `MDY`.